# Kubuntu shows black screen after upgrading to 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 16.04, plasma

I upgraded my Kubuntu 15.10 machine to 16.04 yesterday. Everything was working fine. Today, I did a reboot. Upon logging in, my desktop doesn't show so I have a blank black screen. Thankfully, Plank was able to start so I have access to a terminal, file browser, and Chrome.

What can I do to fix this? I'm assuming this is a problem with Plasma, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: Actually I was having the same problem and managed to solve it after a rough battle with my nVidia drivers. May I ask whether you have a nVidia graphic card?

Comment: @0x450 I don't have an Nvidia card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `kscreen` got uninstalled somehow. I reinstalled it and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with a splash screen going straight to a black screen, with no graphical login.

To fix this, I purged `nvidia-*`, installed `nouveau`, and then realized that both `lightdm` and `sddm` were installed. I purged both of those and reinstalled `sddm`.

Comment: This worked, thank you. Nvidia driver turned out to be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

I had a black screen also on an old Thinkpad T43p after upgrade form 14.04 -> 16.04. It was fixed after

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall sddm; sudo dpkg-reconfigure sddm
```

After reboot I my had graphical login, but my user was missing (UID=501).

Fixing required creation of `/etc/sddm.conf` with lines

```
[Users]
MinimumUid=500
```